# Can't your boss just sign a contract promising a raise or a bonus at some future date?

Tags: compensation, bonus

It seems a too common situation I read here and other places where the boss promise a bonus or a raise in exchange of employee retention and/or other things, and then backs down when it is time pay. This very issue is the reason of [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/167447/my-manager-with-a-history-of-reneging-on-bonuses-is-offering-a-future-bonus-to). I see not a single answer suggesting OP to get a written contract like "In exchange of not resigning in period X, boss will pay OP a bonus of value Y on date Z, and OP's salary will be higher value W from date Q onwards".

Why is that so? Why such a contract is not enforceable/desirable?

Comment: What you propose is basically extortion, and I doubt any boss will agree to such terms.

Comment: Well clearly you didn't read all the answers because one does suggest a contract, and yes that was posted long before you asked this question. -- I would suggest the reason is, it's easy for a boss to make an empty promise but would be almost impossible for an employee to get a contract such as this signed.

Comment: @flexi counter-point: when hired I had twice automatic payment increases in the contract. Sure, OP's phrasing is err improvable, like you shouldn't go with an "exchange" but rather ask to get a promise in writing now if it is so sure that it will happen in a year (and just leave if they don't budge). But it's not outlandish and actually exactly what contracts are for, to make hard promises and regulate what happens when you break 'em.

Comment: @FrankHopkins I don't disagree with your point. I see employment as a 2 way street, and getting a contract like this shouldn't be an issue. However, getting an employer to sign something like this once you're already an employee... I think it would be hard to get them to sign. When joining you have more leverage. -- Leverage here may be "I need a pay rise to justify staying", but I think an employer would still think they have the advantage until the employee gives their notice. The advantage then goes back to the employee, but they risk their job if no counter (singing the contract) is given

Comment: If they value your work you don't need a contract. If they don't value your work, or not up to your expectations, you probably should look for something else. I always consider there's a tacit contract between me and my employer: if working there is not making me happy, I'll leave.

Comment: The situation where boss promise a bonus or a raise in the future usually arises as a counteroffer or a when the employer fears the employee will leave the company when they can't afford to lose that person. This is exactly the case with the linked question, where the employer approached employee and promised a bonus and a raise, which is basically an admission the employee has the leverage.

Comment: "What you propose is basically extortion, and I doubt any boss will agree to such terms." @sf02  It's no more extortion than any other request to put a verbal commitment on paper.

Answer (score 2):

My boss agreed a promotion with me in writing a year in advance.

We set out the various things I needed to achieve within the year and if I met all of them I would be promoted.

Not sure on the legally of it as he held up his end and promoted me at the end of the year, so I never had to challenge it.

Comment: It would have been enforceable, however, by enforcing it you pretty much kill the employee employer relationship.  It typically ends up being a situation where you ask yourself “do I really want to work here?” so what ends up being enforced will vary greatly.